# Meaning behind Extreme arith overflow error

Tags: java

I'm new to Java, and I'm wondering what can be done in the implementation below so that I wouldn't face with the aforementioned error in the question.

The coding question can be found here ==> [Triangle: Determine if an array includes a triangular triplet (Codility)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912099/triangle-determine-if-an-array-includes-a-triangular-triplet-codility)

My solution is as follows:

```java
// you can also use imports, for example:
// import java.util.*;

// you can write to stdout for debugging purposes, e.g.
// System.out.println("this is a debug message");
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8
        boolean isTriangle = false;
        List<Integer> myTriangleList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i : A){
            myTriangleList.add(i);
        }
        Collections.sort(myTriangleList);

        for(int i = 0; i<myTriangleList.size()-2;i++){
            if(myTriangleList.get(i)+ myTriangleList.get(i+1)> myTriangleList.get(i+2)){
                isTriangle = true;
                break;}
        }
        if(isTriangle)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

I am  getting the following error though

[image]

This code gives me %93

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, for example, the 3 numbers you are testing are all `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, they represent a valid triangle. However, your `myTriangleList.get(i)+ myTriangleList.get(i+1)> myTriangleList.get(i+2)` test would return `false`, because the addition of the first two numbers will give a negative sum, due to numeric overflow.

You can check if the sum is negative, and in that case accept the 3 numbers as a triangle:

```
if (myTriangleList.get(i) > 0 &&
    myTriangleList.get(i+1) > 0 &&
    myTriangleList.get(i+2) > 0 && 
    (myTriangleList.get(i) + myTriangleList.get(i+1) > myTriangleList.get(i+2) ||
   myTriangleList.get(i) + myTriangleList.get(i+1) < 0)) {
    isTriangle = true;
    break;
}
```

EDIT: added conditions to handle negative numbers.

Comment: But in this case an array like [-2,-2,-2] will also return 1, which fails the tests

Comment: @BurakhanAksoy Well, if the input can contain negative values, you have to add another test - if any of the 3 numbers is negative, this is an invalid triplet.